# Are there any adventures/campaigns that centre around a university/college in D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures

I'm working on a character that is like a Maester/Scholar/University Professor (or whatever the D&D equivalent of a university would be).

I was wondering if anyone knew of any adventures that revolved around a university or school in a D&D setting. It doesn't -- and maybe even *shouldn't* -- necessarily need to be a wizarding school/college. Non-magic stuff would be great.

I'd like to dip into them to come up with some official sounding titles, ranks, classes, etc. for my backstory. Bonus points if they have a biology/taxidermy/monster hunting slant to them.

Comment: Is there any reason why I cannot answer this? Dragon Magazine Issue #95 has an adventure that is set in the Myth Drannor School of Wizardry. It is actually the first published adventure set in the Forgotten Realms.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, ruffdove!